# Slightly move an element following the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a kind of parallax effect for my elements. I'd like them to slightly move following the movement of the cursor (a movement of 10px max).

I've managed to rotate my element on its own axis following the cursor with this code i found.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 var myContainer = $('#menuu');
 var sensitivityMultiplier = 0.03;
 var wrapperOffset = myContainer.offset();
 var CenterX = wrapperOffset.left + (myContainer.width()/2) ;
 var CenterY = wrapperOffset.top + (myContainer.height()/2) ;
 
 $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
 var mouseX = e.pageX;
 var mouseY = e.pageY;
 doAwesomeness(mouseX,mouseY);
 });
 
function doAwesomeness(mouseX,mouseY){
 var RelX = ( mouseX - CenterX ) * sensitivityMultiplier;
 var RelY = ( ( mouseY - CenterY ) * -1 ) * sensitivityMultiplier;
 myContainer.css('-webkit-transform', 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + RelX + 'deg) rotateX(' + RelY + 'deg)' );
 myContainer.css('transform', 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + RelX + 'deg) rotateX(' + RelY + 'deg)' );
 };
 
});
</script>
```

But what i'm trying to achieve is more a "translate" than a "rotate".
Any help ?

Comment: Do you mean, more of a skewing effect?

Comment: No, i really mean translate : like moving my element 10px left if my mouse is at the left of the screen for instance.

Comment: You're saying your answer right in your question... You want to use `translate` instead of `rotate`. See the answer I posted below. Am I missing something about your question or did you not even look at the code for something called 'rotate' before you asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are trying to achieve a translate not a rotate, so use `translateX` instead of `rotateX` and `translateY` instead of `rotateY`. Then just change your units to pixels instead of degrees.

```
function doAwesomeness(mouseX,mouseY){
  var RelX = ( mouseX - CenterX ) * sensitivityMultiplier;
  var RelY = ( ( mouseY - CenterY ) * -1 ) * sensitivityMultiplier;
  myContainer.css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY(' + RelX + 'px) translateX(' + RelY + 'px)' );
  myContainer.css('transform', 'translateY(' + RelX + 'px) translateX(' + RelY + 'px)' );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i wanted ;). I did replace rotateY by translateY in the first place, though i didn't think about replacing the degrees with pixels. My mistake. Do you think that it's possible to apply this process to the nearest element only (say i have multiples <li>) ?